# Angular 5, Chart.js displaying multiple charts, one on each tab

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, angular5

I can display a single chart without problems, but I am trying to display that chart once per tab of a mat-tab-group, of course with the data being different on each tab. The chart will be part of a bigger 'dashboard' of several charts, so I have implemented it as a child component of the component that displays the tabs.

Parent component (tabs):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  template: '<mat-tab-group>
               <mat-tab *ngFor="let store of stores" label="{{store.store_code}}">
                 <app-store-dash-board [store_code]="store.store_code"></app-store-dash-board>
               </mat-tab>
             </mat-tab-group>'
})

export class myTabsComponent implements OnInit {
stores: any;

constructor(){}

ngOnInit(){ this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data=> {this.stores=data['stores']}
}
```

Child component (charts):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-store-dash-board',
  template: '<canvas id='my_canvas'>{{ my_chart }}</canvas>'
})

export class StoreDashBoardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() store_code: String;

  my_chart = [];

  constructor(private sales_data: FinancialService) { }

  ngOnInit() {this.displaySalesChart(this.store_code);}
}

  displaySalesChart(store) { this.sales_data.getData(store).subscribe(data => {
      this.sales = data['sales_data'];

  this.my_chart = new Chart('my_canvas', { type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: this.sales.dates, 
      datasets: <JSON>storedatasets
    },
    options: { . . }
   });
}
```

}

This code is simplified for clarity. The chart and data display fine using `<app-store-dash-board>` as a stand-alone component showing one chart for one store, but when I make it a child component of the `<app-tabs>` component expecting one chart per tab, the chart renders on the first tab, does not render on the subsequent tabs, and the chart on the first tab shows data from other tabs if I hover over it. I have debugged the `@Input() store_code: String` variable and know it contains the expected value for each tab.

I suspected the problem has something to do with drawing on the same canvas (my_canvas) and storing data into the same variable (my_chart[]) for every chart, so I have tried a variable canvas id in the child component:

```
template: '<canvas id={{this.store_code}}>{{ my_chart }}</canvas>'
.
.
this.my_chart = new Chart(this.store_code, { type: 'line',
.
.
```

but the result on console is:

```
(5) core.controller.js:118 Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item
```

The (5) is an important clue, because in the dataset I'm testing with, I have *6 tabs* being displayed. The chart on the first tab *is* rendered, but the charts on the remaining tabs are not rendered and produce the 5 errors. The chart on the first tab continues to have the issue of showing the wrong data when I hover over.

So, I think I'm close to a solution, but I'm not understanding fully. Any help?

Comment: I've done a lot of work with chart.js in Angular, and I can promise you that you want to re-use the same component/container as much as possible. Rather than have 6 hard coded charts you might want to just move the same chart around and change the data. The reason is the chart DOM is heavy, and you can expect to overload browsers if you render too many (slower computers will crash with 3, even)

Comment: I'm not an expert in charts but I saw, as you mention already that you are using the same canvas id. Further more I don't know if the subsequent tab are already created to add canvas on it. My sugestion is read the canvas as a viewchild or elementref and track the active tab in order to display the sub component only when the parent tab is active.

Answer (score 1):

Tab contents of mat-tabs can be lazy loaded by declaring the body in a ng-template with the matTabContent attribute. Additionally each chart should has its own canvas/context (property canvasID):

```
 <mat-tab *ngFor="let store of stores" label="{{store.store_code}}">
   <ng-template matTabContent>
     <app-store-dash-board [store_code]="store.store_code" [canvasId]="store.canvasId"></app-store-dash-board>
   </ng-template>
 </mat-tab>
```

Answer (score -1):

U must create the canvas with Id and get the context when the component is loading.

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

// Variables
  canvas: any;
  ctx: any;
// Chart de Chart.Js
 chart: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.createChart();
  }

  private createChart() {
     this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
       type: 'bar',
       data:,
       options,
     });
 }
```

Try to use ngAfterViewInit so the component dont try to get the context before the DOM is loaded.